# Android : Spinner in a dialog

Tags: android, dialog, spinner

I am trying to put a spinner in a dialog window but it is doesn't work .
the compilation work but when i open the dialog window the app stop to work .

```
 @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                s=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerdevise);
                AddDialog d = new AddDialog(MainActivity.this) ;
                d.setContentView(R.layout.dialogedit);
                ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(d.a,
                        R.array.devise_spin, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                s.setAdapter(adapter);
                d.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                d.show();
            }
```

xml of the dialog:  dialogedit.xml

```
...
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerdevise"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
...
```

String.xml

```
<string-array name="devise_spin">
        <item>azd</item>
        <item>zdad</item>
        <item>sdsfqf</item>
        <item>dadf</item>
        <item>adasd</item>
    </string-array>
```

thanks for help

Comment: show logcat error

Comment: try  d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog); where dialog layout should contain spinner,

Comment: You have not added spinner view in dialog. You need to add view.

Comment: logcat:   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this
i think you forgot to **setContentView** to your dialog set layout to your dialog like below code

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    dialog d = new dialog(MainActivity.this) ;
    d.setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout);// set layout to your dialog

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
        R.array.devise_spin);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    s=(Spinner)d.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    s.setAdapter(adapter);
    d.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    d.show();
}
```

Comment: it's not working

Comment: did you get any error

Comment: logcat:   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference

Comment: show your layout.xml file with question

Comment: don't need all the layout no ?

Comment: show you layout in which you add spinner

Comment: bind your spinner like this `s=(Spinner)d.findViewById(R.id.spinner);`

Comment: ok thanks the app working without bug but i don't see anything in the spinner !

Comment: which array you are passing in adapter@Raphaeld

Comment: <string-array name="devise_spin">
        <item>azd</item>
        <item>zdad</item>
        <item>sdsfqf</item>
        <item>dadf</item>
        <item>adasdsd</item>
    </string-array>

Comment: @Raphaeld check updated ans

Comment: create adapter like this `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
        R.array.devise_spin);`